# How can I get a reference to the element im selecting within a chained functions init call?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Lets say I have the following:

```
$('input[rel]').jOverlay({ overlayId: "#overlayID" });
```

How can I dynamically get the overlayID from the rel value of the input? I have tried using:

```
$('input[rel]').jOverlay({ overlayId: this.attr('rel') });
```

And I have tried wrapping it in an anonymous function:

```
$('input[rel]').jOverlay({ (function() { overlayId: this.attr('rel'); }) });
```

To no avail, what is the right way to do this?

Many Thanks
- Jai

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd have to iterate over them using [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each), otherwise `this` (in your first and second examples) is actually the `window` and not the element (also, `this` wouldn't make sense if you had multiple elements matched).

```
$('input[rel]').each(function () {
     // In here, this is the specific element in the 
     // jQuery set we're iterating over.

     $(this).jOverlay({ overlayId: this.rel });
});
```

The reason the third won't work is most likely the plugin you're using doesn't support that parameter list.

Comment: thank you for the explanation of why they examples didn't work, this helped a lot